# Why Random Access Machine could only have $N \leq 2^{W}$ memory slots? Is it general theorem of informal rule?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computation-models

Here: 
$W$ is "bitness" - number of bits in one machine word, that could be stored in memory slots 
$N$ - number of memory slots (each has bitness equals $W$)

**My solution:** 
If max length of machine word is $W$ so there are $2^{W}$ different machine words. Suppose, that each possible machine word works like an address of appropriate slot. Hence if $N > 2^{W}$ there will be slot, that couldn't be accessed by address of machine word.

**Problem:** 
I don't actually like my solution, because you may use RAM like an assembler and if $W$ is relatively small. For example if $W=1$ and $N=6$, what will be wrong if we manually will LOAD data to 6th slot of RAM? But on the other hand real systems are much more reliable and addressing is really important (it isn't safe to use manual indexing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial solution sounds correct to me.

The problem with your second idea of switching between RAM sticks, using a "select RAM stick" instruction, is that it technically is not random-access anymore:

- Reading data from only one DIMM requires 1 op per access (switch address)
- Switching between DIMMs requires up to 2 ops per access (switch address + switch RAM stick)

Even if you were to use a single instruction that reads 2 registers at once, it will require 2 ops to set the registers. If you add an operation that writes two registers at once you have arguably increased the effective word/register length.

It is worth pointing out that modern computers are *not* true random-access machines anymore. RAM DIMMs consist of banks of rows, each coming with switching overhead. Modern CPUs try to predict and prefetch memory regions that are going to be required next which makes predictable memory access faster than random-access. Memory is read in chunks (cache lines) which makes sequential
access faster than strided access.